# Is it possible to cheat on Devil May Cry 4 on PC?

Tags: pc, cheats, devil-may-cry-4

Is it possible to cheat on Devil May Cry 4 on PC?

I hate the skill learning principle of this game. I would like to start the game with all skills. Is there a cheat code to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a "[debug mode](http://s1.zetaboards.com/InfernalWorks/topic/3745063/1/)" available for some of the PC versions. To quote the thread linked:

> **What is debug mode?**
>
> It's a menu with special options used by capcom
>   for testing DMC 4, only available in the PC version. Features include
>   playing as Dante whenever you want, infinite jumps, invincibilty,
>   disabling cutscenes, no-clip, and others. It was apparently not
>   removed in a multi-9 version of the game which came in a polish
>   magazine, CD-Action.
>
> **Great, how do I use it?**
>
> If you have the CD-Action version, press and
>   hold L1+L2 and then press R1 to toggle Debug Mode. If you don't, the
>   Infernal Works community made a patch to enable it in all versions,
>   get it here: http://s1.zetaboards.com/InfernalWorks/topic/3739265/1/

Though it *seems* to be a legit version of the game's executable, I'd suggest getting the CD-Action version (easy if you're in or near Poland, might be tricky elsewhere) in preference of relying on an "unofficial patch" provided by a random internet forum.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there are no cheat codes available for Devil May Cry 4.